# Wifi unavailable during Network request

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I am calling a web service Synchronously using AFNetowrking. For example i am uploading some data to server and while uploading the wifi is out. How would i know that wifi is unavailable and cancel the request?

Comment: are you using reachability classes

Comment: Yes. Checking for wifi before the synchronous request. But while it is in progress that s the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that you have used Reachability class or not. But if not used than it is given in below Apple sample code.

[Reachability Introduction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/reachability/introduction/intro.html)

Include these class in your project. Now with the help of `AppDelegate.m` file you can track availability of network.

Add notification observer in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. This will notify on network changes.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{        
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityDidChange:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
}
```

The notification method will call when there is any change in host connectivity or network connectivity.

```
- (void)reachabilityDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {

    Reachability *reachability = (Reachability *)[notification object];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    switch (internetStatus) {
        case NotReachable: {
            NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
            break;
        }

        case ReachableViaWiFi: {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");
            break;
        }

        case ReachableViaWWAN: {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");
            break;
        }
    }

    NetworkStatus hostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    switch (hostStatus) {
        case NotReachable: {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is down.");
            break;
        }

        case ReachableViaWiFi: {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WIFI.");
            break;
        }

        case ReachableViaWWAN: {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WWAN.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Cancel `NSURLConnection` request when you lost connectivity.

To cancel on going request use `- (void)cancel;` method of `NSURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

What about retrying request until WiFi if alive again?

Try this cocoapod: https://github.com/shaioz/AFNetworking-AutoRetry